# Complex regular expression to handle number sequence

Tags: regex, numbers

Hi I have been upto a difficult regular expression to handle of which I have very limited knowledge. It would be great if someone can let me understand how to interprete such problem:

Description:
given a string of digits such as `1234567` I will have to come up with a regex that will output the result as :

```
12
23
34
45
56
67
```

I am not asking for a direct solution rather a guideline will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In perl, you could:

```
echo 1234567|perl -ne 's/(?<!^)(.)(?!$)/$1\n$1/g; print;'
```

`(?<!^)` is a [negative look-behind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) (for the start of the string `^`).
`(?!$)` is a negative look-ahead assertion (for the end of the string `$`). The regex will match all characters except the first and last. The replacement repeats the matched character with a newline in the middle.

Comment: That's pretty neat - didn't think to repeat the character. +1

Answer (score 1):

You don't state which language you are using but I will assume it supports positive lookahead - most of them do.

Here is a solution in Java:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String in = "1234567";
    final Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\d{2})).");
    final Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(in);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
12
23
34
45
56
67
```

The pattern is `(?=(\d{2})).` (you need the `\\` in Java for language syntax reasons).

Explanation:

- `(?=(\d{2}))` this is the meat of the solution and it's a little tricky, it is a positive lookahead assertion that checks for two digits following the current point in the input `String`. It then grabs those two digits - this is where the "output" comes from.
- `.` this matches any character (it could also be `\d` but that's not required). This ensures that the regex engine moves along one space at a time.

So initially the engine is as the start of the `String`. The assertion captures `12` and the `.` captures **and consumes** the `1`. Now the engine is after the `1`, the assertion captures `23` and the `.` captures **and consumes** `2`. Etc...

The trick it that the assertion is capturing two characters at a time but the pattern is only advancing one character at a time.

This one-liner does a replacement rather than a search - in Java `String`s are immutable so the result is actually a different `String` - the `String in` is not modified by the operation:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("1234567".replaceAll("(?=(\\d{2})).(?=\\d{2})", "$1\n"));
}
```

Here we need to add another assertion that there are at least two more digits to consume after this one. Output:

```
12
23
34
45
56
67
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do as well with Perl one liner:

```
echo 1234567 | perl -ne "$\=$/; print for $_=~/(?=(\d\d))/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex isn't going to output anything, it's going to find text that matches. I guess your 'output' is actually a list of all the matches.

So you need a regex that will find all of those number pairs within the search text.